# gdb input/output buffer not working

Tags: debugging, gdb

I start gdb (with many-windows) through `projectile-run-gdb` but stdin/out is not displayed in the input/output buffer.

And I have no clue where to look for the issue. Google search did not bring up any good answers. Can somebody give me a good starting point?

If I start gdb from the command line, printed output is showing up in the terminal as expected.

Emacs Version: 28.0.50

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the target output stream is not redirected while debugging on a remote target, so you need to set this.

This snippet helped me solving the issue:

```
(defun private-gdbmi-bnf-target-stream-output (c-string)
  "Change behavior for GDB/MI target the target-stream-output so that it is displayed to the console."
  (gdb-console c-string)
  )

(advice-add 'gdbmi-bnf-target-stream-output :override 'private-gdbmi-bnf-target-stream-output)
```